# Erro: module import emoji no found

Tags: python

Estou praticando uma aula de python e preciso baixar a biblioteca emoji para que o programa depois de executado imprima o emoji que o usuario digitou.

Porém, na hora de executar, diz que a biblioteca não está instalada.

Eu segui minusciosamente os passos de tutorial na internet de como instalá-la no Sublime e, mesmo assim, não funcionou.

Como devo proceder?

Meu código:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Olá, Mundo :sunglasses:'))
```

O erro apresentado é:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emoji'

Comment: Como você instalou o módulo?

Comment: Btw, eu editei sua pergunta e troquei as imagens por texto. Por favor, **não faça publicações com imagens ao invés de texto**, fica difícil de ler, de entender, de reproduzir e prejudica as pessoas que não conseguem ver imagens por causa de bloqueios ou problemas de visão. Apenas use imagens para ilustrar sua publicação.

Comment: bom, eu usei o controle de pacotes e instalei o pacote python fix, me baseei por esse link  [link] (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Fix%20Imports)

Comment: Comentário do autor da pergunta postado erroneamente como sinalização para a moderação: *bom, eu pesquisei no google e vi que um dos problemas poderia estar em uma das linhas de comando nas configurações do sublime que estava ignorando os pacotes: "ignored_packages": [ "Vintage" ], e mesmo depois de apaga-la e reiniciar o software, ainda nao leu o pacote fix imports*

Answer (score 2):

O erro diz que a biblioteca não está sendo importada.

Instale usando o terminal da sua própria IDE, ou do seu próprio sistema operacional usando o seguinte comando:

```
pip install emoji
```

E depois:

```
pip install emoji --upgrade
```

Segue abaixo vários exemplos, tanto na IDE quanto no terminal do SO:

[image: print de exemplo]

Seria ideal você também criar um ambiente virtual, assim consegue instalar várias bibliotecas.

Answer (score -2):

Me deparei com esse problema e resolvi da seuinte forma.

Pycharm > File > Settings > Pasta do projeto > Python Interpreter

Removi o:
Django
Django-emoji
emoji

e depois intalei o emoji

abri o prompt pip install emoji

após isso coloquei no pycharm novamente

coloquei o código e rodou perfeitamente.