# Como fazer python3 reconhecer o módulo emoji?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu fiz a instalação do módulo emoji com

```
sudo apt-get install python-emoji
```

Depois de instalado, eu confirmei a instalação com

```
pip install emoji
```

Eu recebo a mensagem

```
Collecting emoji
Installing collected packages: emoji
Successfully installed emoji-0.5.4
```

No entanto, `import emoji` é reconhecido no python2 mas não é reconhecido no python3. O programa `testes.py`, dado por

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('ola, mundo! :thumbs_up:'))
```

Roda corretamente com `python testes.py`, mas com `python3 testes.py` retorna a mensagem

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emoji'
```

Parece que o python3 não encontra o módulo. Como resolver este problema?

Eu uso o editor `vi` sob Xubunto.

Nota 1: Eu verifiquei [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/328501/190793) pergunta, mas ela não responde à minha pergunta. Eu já tenho o módulo instalado e o python2 consegue rodá-lo. Mas o python3, que eu uso mais, não consegue acessar o módulo.

Nota 2: Eu consegui instalar com

```
$ git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji.git

$ cd emoji

$ python setup.py install
```

Porém, eu agora recebo a mensagem

```
AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'
```

Nota 3: Eu descobri que o problema é que as bibliotecas do emoji estão disponíveis para o python3.6 mas não para o python3.8. Eu consigo rodar o programa normalmente com

```
python3.6 testes.py
```

No entanto, com  `python3.8 testes.py` eu recebo a mensagem

```
AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'
```

Como eu faço para que o python3.8 tenha acesso às bibliotecas do módulo?

Answer (score 3):

Como você já disse que tem duas versões do python rodando, com resultados diferentes para cada versão, então é provável que sua versão padrão do sistema seja o python 2. Tente o seguinte:

1. Verifique se o pip3 está instalado:

   $ pip3 --version
2. Caso ***não*** esteja:

   $ sudo apt update

   $ sudo apt install python3-pip
3. caso esteja instalado:

   $ pip3 install emoji

Comment: Eu segui os passos e não funcionou. Continuo a receber o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Pedro, e quando faz `python3 -m pip install emoji`?

Comment: @GustavoSampaio, eu tentei, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Eu obtenho o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar usando o python 2 como padrão do sistema, portanto quando você usa o pip ele instala o pacote para o python 2. 
Tente assim:

```
pip3 install emoji
```

Comment: Eu segui esses passos e não funcionou. Continuo a receber a mesma mensagem de erro.